# Flurry on Blackberry 10

Tags: blackberry-10, flurry

is it possible to use Flurry Blackberry SDK on Blackberry 10?
Flurry SDK:
http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted/TechnicalQuickStart/Blackberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Flurry now appears to support BB10.

No, Flurry seems to be only for BB 5, 6 and 7 (the Java BlackBerry's).

For BB10, the only analytics that I know of, is [Count.ly](http://www.count.ly), for which I (shameless plug) wrote the [BB10 SDK](https://github.com/craigmj/countly-sdk-blackberry10-cascades) for Cascades. You can also use it from QML.

Count.ly is Open Source. You can use their hosted service, or you can run your own Count.ly server. It's excellent.